# Firefox on-the-fly search engine change

Tags: firefox, search

I consult a lot of different searchable sites for information, and I was wondering if there's an add-on or inbuilt feature to have Firefox use a different search engine on-the-fly.

For example, if I wanted to search wikipedia specifically, I would type something like

```
wp Cats
```

and it would search Wikipedia for cats. I would want to be able to have multiple different search providers that I could switch between using this methodology.

Does an addon exist for this or would I have to create such an addon?

I remember in Opera you could do something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for an add-on, it is built in into Firefox (as well as Chrome). Here is how to do it (source: [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar))

- Visit the page on the target website that has the search field that you would normally use to search the site.
- Right-click on the search field. Select `Add a Keyword for this Search....`
- The Add Bookmark dialog appears. Enter an appropriate name for the bookmark (e.g. "The Internet Movie Database"). Create a keyword (e.g. "imdb").
- Select the bookmark folder to contain the smart keyword. Click `OK`

To use the created smart bookmark, enter the keyword and the search string in the Location bar and then press Enter.